# Unexpected behavior from CONCAT in sql server with some strange, non null value : the value after it are not added to the result

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

```
SELECT CONCAT('a', ISNULL(NameStudent, 'ccc'), 'b') as ShouldEndWithb,  NameStudent, LEN(NameStudent) as Length
FROM #Student
```

There is a strange NameStudent value that gives the result below from this request in ssms. I don't understand why the Concat doesn't end with b and why this seemingly empty value has a length of 2. And after understanding this, I want to know what should I do to have CONCAT behave as expected.

| ShouldEndWithb | NameStudent | Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a |  | 2 |

Comment: Sounds like this might be some sort of a special characters like a Carriage Return or something along those lines. Typically this can be encountered when data was copy/pasted into whatever is your source.

Comment: Cast it to `varbinary(100)` and examine it.

Comment: How did the row get into `#Student`? What is the definition of `#Student`? The data behind the query is much more important than the query itself. This isn't necessarily unexpected behavior from `CONCAT`, it's almost certainly bad data.

Comment: CONVERT(varbinary(100), NameStudent) is equal to 0x00000000.
The data came from a bulk import of a csv

Comment: That's bad data and is [exactly what I would expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpfQk.png). `0x00` is the zero-byte character and effectively terminates the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's bad data and is exactly what I would expect:

> [image]

`0x00` is the zero-byte character and effectively terminates the string.

You need to fix the source to not send 0x00, because the data is already gone.

Comment: I can't fix the source of the data, but I can simply check if the data is equal to 0x00000000 then replace it with '' to get the wanted behavior. Thanks.
SELECT CONCAT('a', CASE WHEN CONVERT(varbinary(100), NameStudent) = 0x00000000 THEN '' ELSE NameStudent END , 'b') Return 'ab'

Comment: @Ant but is it not important that the source should have given you an actual name and you're stuck with an empty string? You're right that from a T-SQL perspective you can work around this but it doesn't make a whole lot of sense from the business logic side.

Comment: "effectively" means that 0x00 characters don't terminate the string _inside_ SQL Server_.  But many, many client libraries interpret a 0x00 as a null terminator for a string.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft It's why I said effectively. As a practical matter I'm not sure how important it is _where_ the termination happens. It could have happened long before the CSV file was created.

Comment: I was just being pedantic about _where_ the truncation happens.

Comment: @aaron-bertrand, the value can be null or empty for this case. I don't know why they decide for some columns to put 0x00000000 instead of an empty string, but I will simply assume they secretly hate me